# Toggle between accelerometer and touchDown in libGDX

Tags: libgdx, accelerometer

I'm using the touchDown method (InputProcessor)to move a sprite in the x-axis, i also want it to be moved using the accelerometer.

Is there a way in libGDX to toggle between the two methods and can they both be implemented together (so that the movement is done using the accelerometer as long as the screen is not touched or will they conflict with each other when phone is tilted and screen is touched)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do [polling](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Polling).

```
if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
  // screen touched logic
} else {
  // check for accelerometer
  float accelX = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX();
  float accelY = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY();
  float accelZ = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerZ();
  // do stuff with the accel(s)
}
```

Comment: can it be done in a way that i can only let one be usable but both available, so i can later on put it as an option in the game settings to turn accelerometer on and off.

Comment: you can store those options as [preferences](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences), and check for that preferences when you init your screen `prefs.getBoolean("accelerometerEnabled")`